# In jq, what is the opposite of the array iterator (.[])?

Tags: jq

In [the docs](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/), `jq` calls `.[]` the "Array/Object Value Iterator".  What is the opposite operator?

Another way to ask it, is what should I put in this command to leave the output largely unchanged (other than formatting):

```
cat foo.json | jq '.[] | ??what here??' > foo2.json
```

I ask because I want to manipulate each array element, then put it back together, i.e.,

```
cat foo.json | jq '.[] | . += {"changes": "here"} | ??what here??' > foo2.json
```

**EDIT**: I actually need to change a subpart, so:

```
cat foo.json | jq '.[] | .subpart += {"changes": "here"} | ??what here??' > foo2.json
```

Comment: please provide desired input and desired output

Comment: You cannot simply "come back" after descending into the structure. Instead, you can set a surrounding structure that encloses it, making your filter work inside that outer structure. In case of an array, try the array constructor `[‌...]` as in `[.[] + {"changes": "here"}]`), or use the shortcut function `map` that does the same taking your inner filter as argument: `map(. + {"changes": "here"})`. Note that `+ {"changes": "here"}` can be simplified to `.changes = "here"`.

Comment: @pmf Submit one of those code fragments as an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: @pmf FYI, the "map" suggestion also helped me, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly is your input? If you only use `+=` (and not `| .`), it should work already:

```
jq '.[] += {"changes": "here"}' foo.json > foo2.json
```

Example:

```
jq '.[] += {"changes": "here"}' <<JSON
[
  {"a":1},
  {"b":2},
  {"c":3}
]
JSON
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "changes": "here"
  },
  {
    "b": 2,
    "changes": "here"
  },
  {
    "c": 3,
    "changes": "here"
  }
]
```

`.` is the identify filter and does not change its input. `|` "drills down" into whatever filter you have specified to the left of it and makes it the new "root".

Comment: My bad, the question was missing that I need to add it to a subpart, so `jq .[] | .subpart += {"changes": "here"}`.

Comment: @dfrankow `jq '.[].subpart += …` (without the `|` – the last sentence of my answer still applies; I have clarified it a bit)